# if Syntax in pine script

Tags: if-statement, syntax, pine-script

I'm new to pinescript and I can't figure out what's wrong with my if syntax. Please help

```
//@version=4

strategy(title="Weighted Moving ATR", shorttitle="WMATR Stra Test", overlay = true)

//Changing inputs based on ticker
if (syminfo.ticker == "AAPL")
     LenWATR = 43
     MultWATR = 1
else if (syminfo.ticker == "AAL")
     LenWATR = 21
     MultWATR = 1
```

I keep getting line 13: Mismatched input 'LenWATR' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Comment: Thanks to @bajaco & @ Bjorn Mistiaen. I got it to work!
But now is there a way I can debug it to know the LenWATR & MultWATR is the correct value when it's AAPL or AAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because the indentation is wrong.
You're indenting with 5 whitespaces, but indententations should be a multiple of 4 whitespaces.

You could also write it like this:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Weighted Moving ATR", shorttitle="WMATR Stra Test", overlay = true)

var int LenWATR  = na
var int MultWATR = na

//Changing inputs based on ticker
LenWATR := if syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" 
    43
else if syminfo.ticker == "AAL"
    1
else
    99 // default value

MultWATR := if syminfo.ticker == "AAL" 
    1
else if syminfo.ticker == "AAL"
    1
else
    77 // default value

//Changing inputs based on ticker: short version
LenWATR  := syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" ? 43 : syminfo.ticker == "AAL" ? 1 : 99
MultWATR := syminfo.ticker == "AAPL" ?  1 : syminfo.ticker == "AAL" ? 1 : 77

plot(na)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had used 4 spaces before and it didn't work for overflow line, I had to use 5, that's why I use 5 here.
Now that I used 4 spaces, the error is now said now it said "Syntax error at input 'syminfo.ticker'"  Do you know how I'm suppose to use the info from syminfo.ticker?
Aslo I use == instead of = now

Comment: Please show your entire script to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parenthesis. Also if you are using `=` in your if statement blocks you are initializing variables in a local scope. If the variables exist elsewhere value assignment should use `:=`

Comment: I took the parenthese off and now it said "Syntax error at input 'syminfo.ticker'" I thought this is a reserved variable and if my ticker is "AAL" it should be true and execute the line. Do you know how I'm suppose to use the info from syminfo.ticker ?